# How to import json file to mongodb using pyspark (or python)?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, import, pymongo

I'm try to import json in the file to mongodb using pyspark after connection pyspark with mongodb,

I'm using Ubuntu, my file in (file:///home/user/Downloads/newd/hale.json) I write it like this ('home/user/Downloads/newd/hale.json')

```
import json 
from pymongo import MongoClient
client =  MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
with open('home/user/Downloads/newdb/hale.json') as f:
file = json.load(f)
```

Comment: I want to try this code but in JSON (df = spark.read.csv(path = '/home/ahmad/Downloads/newdb/hale.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)

Answer (score 0):

This should worK:

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
client =  MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
with open('home/user/Downloads/newdb/hale.json') as f:
    file = json.load(f)

db = client['mydatabase']
db.mycollection.insert_one(file)
```

Comment: Thank you. I try your code but the same error (IndentationError: expected an indented block)

Comment: In python the identation is an important part of the syntax. I suspect you didn't ident the line "file = json.load(f)" in the code above.

Comment: Thanks, I found this code : >>> df = spark.read.format('json').load('python/test_support/sql/people.json')

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection's method insert_one or insert_many, which is determined by loading your json file if it is after loading list ( originally array) of python dictionaries ( JSON objects) or python dict ( originally JSON object). 

    `#in case of array of dictionaries
    client['your_database']['your_collection'].insert_many(file)
    #in case of dictionary 
    client['your_database']['your_collection'].insert_one(file)`

Comment: `
    with open('dump') as f:
        txt = f.read();
    file = json.loads(txt)
`